# URL recorder in python

Tags: python, firefox

i'm trying to make a FF URL recorder in python. What this plugin will do is whenever user writes a URL and hit enter it will record that url in a file. I've tried building this in win32gui but it did not work. Then tried using XPCOM but can't able to do it cause there is no good easily understandable tutorial for it out there....how can i do this? Thanks

Comment: It's possible to write stuff using XULRunner with Python (XPCOM and PyXPCOM), but if this is all you want to do, *you don't want to do it in Python.* It will be a *lot* more work to get it set up properly and you won't be able to easily distribute it if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want it to be done in Python?

You can read [this article of how to How to create Firefox extensions](http://roachfiend.com/archives/2004/12/08/how-to-create-firefox-extensions/). It's not Python, but it might help you get the job done.

Comment: i've asked same question to my lead and the reply was "Because client wants it". And i've  already seen that link.

Comment: Maybe the client does not know that it would cost him several times more to have it in python than with XUL / javascript - anyway - if he wants to pay ...

Comment: the article isn't compatible for ff4  or ff5.